# Converting Double to DateTime?

Tags: c#, excel, datetime, datetime-format

I have a .CSV file which I am reading into a C# program. In one of the columns, there is a date, but it is in the "general" format, so it shows up in the .CSV as a number. For example: 41172.

How can I convert this number to a date with format dd/mm/yyyy in C#? 41172 is equivalent to 20/09/2012.

Comment: I agree there is no such date format as I know i asp.net! Its just a random number! You sholud try to export a valid date to CSV file. What program is creating CSV file?

Comment: Does DateTime.FromOADate(41172) work for you?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

EDIT: As noted in comments and other answers, [`DateTime.FromOADate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate.aspx) is a much better approach. I'll remove this answer if it's ever unaccepted. (But, there are still platforms like .NET Core where `FromOADate` is not supported so it is still useful for people using these platforms.)

I suspect you want:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1).AddDays(days - 2);
```

(See other answers for why you need to subtract 2.)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate.aspx - "number of days before or after the base date, midnight, 30 December 1899"

Comment: And the rumor is: because 1900 was not a leap-year but somebody forgot.

Comment: it seems to be consistent so i can just subtract 2. thanks very much.

Comment: @HenkHolterman The story I've heard was to maintain compatibility with Lotus 1-2-3 which had this bug originally.

Comment: @dash: and how did it get into Lotus?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Classic Recursion bug; they thought they were maintaining compatibility with Microsoft ;-)

Comment: @Paul: If you unaccept this answer to accept another one (e.g. dash's) I'll delete this one.

Answer (score 34):

To go from an DateTime in the "Excel Format" to a C# Date Time you can use the [DateTime.FromOADate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate.aspx) function.

In your example above:

```
   DateTime myDate = DateTime.FromOADate(41172);
```

To write it out for display in the desired format, use:

```
   myDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

If you are wondering where the discrepancies in Excel's date handling come from, it's supposed to be on purpose:

> When Lotus 1-2-3 was first released, the program assumed that the year
>   1900 was a leap year even though it actually was not a leap year. This
>   made it easier for the program to handle leap years and caused no harm
>   to almost all date calculations in Lotus 1-2-3.
>
> When Microsoft Multiplan and Microsoft Excel were released, they also
>   assumed that 1900 was a leap year. This allowed Microsoft Multiplan
>   and Microsoft Excel to use the same serial date system used by Lotus
>   1-2-3 and provide greater compatibility with Lotus 1-2-3. Treating
>   1900 as a leap year also made it easier for users to move worksheets
>   from one program to the other.
>
> Although it is technically possible to correct this behavior so that
>   current versions of Microsoft Excel do not assume that 1900 is a leap
>   year, the disadvantages of doing so outweigh the advantages.

Source: http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/ExcelDateandTimes.htm

Comment: Here's another fun anecdote about that same idiosyncrasy: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/06/16.html

Answer (score 3):

In case you are looking for `FromOADate` in .Net Core it is not there.

I dissembled the implementation .Net Framework and created an extension method.

```
        public static DateTime FromOADate(this double date)
        {
            return new DateTime(DoubleDateToTicks(date), DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
        }

        internal static long DoubleDateToTicks(double value)
        {
            if (value >= 2958466.0 || value <= -657435.0)
                throw new ArgumentException("Not a valid value");
            long num1 = (long)(value * 86400000.0 + (value >= 0.0 ? 0.5 : -0.5));
            if (num1 < 0L)
                num1 -= num1 % 86400000L * 2L;
            long num2 = num1 + 59926435200000L;
            if (num2 < 0L || num2 >= 315537897600000L)
                throw new ArgumentException("Not a valid value");
            return num2 * 10000L;
        }
```

Still need to test it.

Answer (score 2):

The date format used by Excel is old, but is still supported by the [DateTime.FromOADate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate.aspx) function, which you can use to convert this number.  It is defined as

> number of days before or after the base date, midnight, 30 December
>   1899

Answer (score -1):

I've seen this from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate.aspx, but I actually think it's wrong.

The real issue is that Excel erroneously supposes that the century year (1900) is a leap year, whereas in fact it was not, but 2000 WAS!

To check this out, try formatting a cell in Excel as Date and then enter `1` and it gives `1 Jan 1900`. Now enter `59` and it gives `28 Feb 1900`. `60` gives `29 Feb 1900` (not a real date) and then `61` gives `01 March 1900`.

So...

```
switch (days)
{
   case < 1:
     // Not valid. Do whatever...
   break;
   case < 59:
     DateTime date = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1).AddDays(days);
   break;
   default:
     // Knock off the extra days caused by 29 Feb 1900 and 29 Feb 2000
     DateTime date = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1).AddDays(days-2);
   break;
}
```

Comment: 2000 _is_ a leap-year. Just like 1600 and 2400. So you're only right about 1900.

Comment: @Henk: Thank you! I did know this, but somehow forgot. Lol, I am a moron! I will edit my answer...