# Why does DateTime.AddDays no longer round to the nearest millisecond in .NET 7?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, .net-core

The [.NET 7 documentation of `DateTime.AddDays(double)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.adddays?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-7.0#System_DateTime_AddDays_System_Double_) says

> The value parameter is rounded to the nearest millisecond.

However, this is apparently no longer true in .NET 7. Consider the following minimal example ([fiddle .NET 4.7.2](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zwmCQT), [fiddle .NET 7](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xLnpy2)):

```
var d = 42005.416666666664; // Excel date
var date = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).AddDays(d - 2.0);

Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("o"));

// .NET 4.8: Prints 2015-01-01T10:00:00.0000000
// .NET 7:   Prints 2015-01-01T09:59:59.9999997
```

**Is this a deliberate change (i.e. is the documentation buggy/outdated), or did I discover a bug in .NET 7?**

---

Notes:

- I know about "floating-point imprecision". That's not the issue here, since DateTime internally uses (precise) ticks.
- Related question about the *motivation* behind rounding to the nearest millisecond: [Why does DateTime.AddDays round to nearest millisecond?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27027033/87698)
- I know that [the correct way to convert "Excel dates"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11968570/87698) is to use `FromOADate`, which *does* round correctly. This is just a minimal example to demonstrate the discrepancy between the observed and the documented behavior of `AddDays`.

Comment: That other question is also only guessing the motivation. I have seen quite a few places where there was a behavior change between .NET Framework and .NET 5.0+ but the documentation stayed unchanged. So I believe it's really just outdated documentation.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/78452

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/7.0/datetime-add-precision

In .NET 7, the behavior of the DateTime.AddDays method has changed, and it no longer rounds to the nearest millisecond. This change was made to align the behavior of DateTime with the behavior of the underlying data type, which is a 64-bit binary representation of the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 0001.

In previous versions of .NET, DateTime was implemented as a structure with a high-precision internal representation, and its value was rounded to the nearest millisecond when it was displayed or converted to a string. However, this rounding could lead to inaccuracies in certain scenarios, such as when adding or subtracting dates.

With the change in .NET 7, the behavior of DateTime has become more predictable and consistent, and it provides a more accurate representation of dates and times. If you need to display a DateTime value with a specific precision, you can use the ToString method and format the output as desired.

It's important to note that this change only affects the behavior of DateTime.AddDays and not other methods of the DateTime structure. The behavior of other methods, such as DateTime.AddHours or DateTime.AddMilliseconds, remains unchanged.

Comment: But it seems that `AddMilliseconds` does no rounding, either.